# Time difference issue of container and host

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, time

I am running container in a Linux VM, the "date" command on VM gives the right time back, while in containers, "date" returns the same result as date on VM. What is different is that when I touch a file in container, and then ls -l this file, the time created is not the same as date in container returned. I tried the same steps on a Centos VM using docker, the date and container file time is the same. Below are the details, could anyone tells me what is the difference?

- In VM: `date` returns: `Fri Jan 10 15:55:37 UTC 2020`
- In Container: `date` returns: `Fri Jan 10 15:55:40 UTC 2020`
- `touch aaaa"` and `ls -l aaaa` returns: `Jan 10 08:03 aaaa`

The issue is date in container should returns the Jan 10 08:03, not the VM time. Is there anything I missed while running a container?

Comment: In the container, is `date` an alias to `date -u` or `TZ= date` or something? How does `\date` behave?

Comment: No, I am running busybox, the ls -l date gives the following output:-rwxr-xr-x  398 502      20         1132888 Dec 23 19:21 /bin/date.

Comment: \date gives me the same result as date:Sun Jan 12 17:14:17 UTC 2020 same as VM

Comment: What is the filesystem type?

Comment: The container is a process of the VM, so if it returns the VM date this is normal?

Comment: But i tried using docker run a busybox and sh into it, the time is 07:XX while my actual VM time is 15:XX. The date in container shows the same result as ls -l a file in container.

Comment: The container bundle is 9p from host into vm.